# Auto-add data from one worksheet to another

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, copying, auto-populate

I am using a spreadsheet to keep track of our files.  I listed the client's last name (column a), first name (column b), date to be destroyed (column c), the aisle & row (columns d & e), status (column f), close date (column g), and close case # (column h).  The formatting is the same on all 3 worksheets, except on worksheet 1, I like to sort by last name. on worksheet 2, I like to sort by close case date.  And worksheet 3, I like to sort by destroy date.  The problem is that I am constantly adding names to the lists because we are continuously closing case files.  How can I add a recently closed case file to worksheet 1 and have it populate automatically into worksheets 2 & 3 without copy & paste?
Example: (Worksheet 1)
Smith, Amy 2016 E 5 Stip 2012 8521
Torres, Jan 2014 A 4 C&R 2010 9124

(Worksheet 2)
Torres, Jan  2014 A 4 C&R 2010 9124
Smith, Amy  2016 E 5 Stip 2012 8521

(Worksheet 3)
Torres, Jan  2014  A 4 C&R 2010  9124
Smith, Amy  2016   E 5 Stip 2012  8521

Answer (score 0):

So, If I understand this correctly, you have the same information on all three tabs, but sorted differently, and the only change is the 'status' of a file, from open, to closed, then to destroy.

This is the kind of task that a database (even MS Access) would do perfectly.

In the meantime, you have two choices, 1) Automation with VBA or 2) combine into one worksheet, and sort as necessary each time.

My view is that you should probably put all the files on the one sheet, and add a new column called 'status' which reflects the open, closed, destroy status. Then enable autofilter

When you want the open view, use auto filter to filter the status column by 'open', and sort the last name column alphabetically.

If selecting and sorting the columns is a pain, then I'd recommend recording a macro where you select & sort for 'open' once, then assign that to a button. Repeat for the other two status, and make two more buttons on your spreadsheet. You'll also need a button for 'unfilter' so record a macro that resets/clears the autofilter.